# Discord Bot Python Delete User Message After Executed

Tags: python, discord

How would I set up my commands so it would delete the author's message after the Discord Bot executed the command? For example:

```
#This is for the 'Ping' command.
if message.content.upper().startswith('!PING'):
userID = message.author.id
await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s> Pong!" % (userID))
```

This command is simple, you type `!ping` and the bot returned with "@mention Pong!". I want to delete the `!ping` sent by the user right after the bot sends out "@mention Pong!".

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so all you have to do is add the following to the end of your code block:

```
await client.delete_message(message)
```

This should delete the 'authors' message after the bot has executed the command.